# How to get a random number upon variable/function call

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def pattern_generator(pattern):
    randomNumber = random.choice(numbers)
    for i in range(1, len(pattern) + 1):
        code= pattern.replace("N", randomNumber, i)
    print(code)
```

pattern_generator("NNNN")

I want to make it so that NNNN consist of different numbers. At the moment its all the same,

eg NNNN --> 3333

I want it to be

NNNN --> 3151.

I know I can make the function above a lot more effective in fewer lines of code. I was just experimenting different ways to see if I can get a new variable. I read upon the random documentation, however I am still confused. If you can provide any insight on how I can do this or any documentation to read upon would be super helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: do you mean something like `"".join(random.choice(numbers) for _ in range(len(pattern)))`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need replace at all for this task, as you want different replacers
Just select a random number as many times as the length of your pattern. For example this will work:

```
def pattern_generator(pattern):
    return''.join([random.choice(numbers) for _ in range(len(pattern))])
```

Example:

```
>>> pattern_generator('NNNN')
'2539'
```

Comment: Yeah I read upon some stuff and found out that going through the string and then appending it to a list would be the most effecient way. My new code is 

```code = []
    for char in pattern:
        randomNumber = random.choice(numbers)
        if char == "N" :
            code.append(randomNumber)  

    print(code)```

Answer (score 0):

randomNumber is inside your function which makes it a local variable. For all the iterations in your for loop the value of the randomNumber variable is the same. Use the random.choice() method directly inside the replace function as follows:

```
def pattern_generator(pattern):
    for i in range(1, len(pattern) + 1):
        code= pattern.replace("N", random.choice(numbers), i)
    print(code)
```

Now, every iteration the for loop has a different random number.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that `re.sub` accepts a callable which takes the current match as an argument. In this case, you aren't actually doing anything with the match:

```
def fill_pattern(haystack):
    import re
    needle = "N"
    def replace(match):
        from string import digits
        from random import choice
        return choice(digits)
    return re.sub(needle, replace, haystack)

print(fill_pattern("Hello NNNN WorNld NNNN"))
```

Output:

```
Hello 4737 Wor3ld 5523
>>>
```

Alternatively, using the length of the current match to sample `str.digits`:

```
def fill_pattern(haystack):
    import re
    needle = "N+"
    def replace(match):
        from string import digits
        from random import sample
        return "".join(sample(digits, k=len(match.group())))
    return re.sub(needle, replace, haystack)
```